# Other counterexamples for this problem on connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> If $A$ is a connected subspace of $X$, does it follow that $\operatorname{Int}A$  and $\operatorname{Bd}A$ are connected? Does the converse hold? Justify your answers.

For original problem, I can easily construct a counterexample. And the converse also fails? I searched this site, and the rationals in $\mathbb{R}$ is counterexample because $\operatorname{Int}A$ is empty (so trivially connected?) and $\operatorname{Bd}A$ is (so connected)?

Can you show more counterexamples?

Comment: To avoid questions about whether the empty set is connected or not (it depends on which definition of connectedness you use), you could take $A=\mathbb Q\cup(0,\infty)$ for your counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

If $A = [0, 1]$ then Bd $A = \{0, 1\}$ is not connected,for  converse  take $A =  \mathbb{Q}$,  Bd$\mathbb{Q}$  and $int\mathbb{Q}$ both  are connnected but  $\mathbb{Q}$ is not  connected